# Backlog and board pages in TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, scrum, backlog

Currently using Team Foundation Server 2012 (version 11.0.50727.1), I have a developers' team working with the backlog and board pages, which is fine.

And I also have a bunch of clients, who are not developers. I would like to give them a sufficient access to be able to see the backlog and board pages. I'm understanding the "limited" rights are not enough.

What permissions are needed to be able to do that? Plus, if I need them to create/edit/delete work items, what licence do they need?

Comment: There are Stake Holder Licenses coming in TFS 2013.4 if you can upgrade.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I don't know when we are going to upgrade but that's a good reason to I guess.

Answer (score 0):

To use the agile planning features in TFS2012 (backlog management and boards) each person must be licensed with either Visual Studio Test Professional, Premium or Ultimate.

If you have CALs for those people you need to ensure their web access permissions are set to Full, via the admin panel.

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/govdev/archive/2012/09/06/license-the-new-tfs-2012-agile-planning-boards.aspx